# Comparing an object member array with a string

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function

First of all, I know you would say this is a known and solved question, but I tried doing it and i get an output that the constant string is not a part of the array.

Specifically, I add an array element called `The_Vale` and when I execute the display function containing the `The_Vale` string, it says "The_Vale is not part of Westeros".

The code looks fine to me, I don't know where the problem is. Can you help me with the function `void display(Kingdom* a, int index, const char *n)`? The other overloaded functions work fine.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "kingdom.h"

namespace westeros {

// TODO:definition for display(...) 

void display(Kingdom& p) {
    cout << p.m_name << ", population " << p.m_population << endl;
}
void display(Kingdom* a, int index) {

    int i;
    int total_pop = 0;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Kingdoms of Westeros" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        total_pop += a[i].m_population;
        cout << i + 1 << "." << a[i].m_name << ", population " << a[i].m_population << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Total population of Westeros :" << total_pop << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
}

void display(Kingdom* a, int index, int min) {
    int i;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Kingdoms of Westeros with more than" << min << " people" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (a[i].m_population >= min) {
            cout << a[i].m_name << ", population " << a[i].m_population << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
}
***void display(Kingdom* a, int index, const char *n) {
    int i;
    int found;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Searching for kingdom " << n << " in Westeros" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        cout << a[i].m_name << " is being compared to " << n << endl;
        if (a[i].m_name == n) {
            found = 1;
            cout << a[i].m_name << ", population " << a[i].m_population << endl;
        }
        else {
            found = 0;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1) {
        cout << a[i].m_name << ", population " << a[i].m_population << endl;
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        cout << n << " is not part of Westeros." << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
}***
}
```

I  call the function in my main `.cpp` file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "kingdom.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace westeros;

int main(void)
{
    int count = 0; // the number of kingdoms in the array

    // TODO: declare the pKingdoms pointer here (don't forget to initialize it)
    Kingdom* pKingdoms = NULL;

    cout << "==========" << endl
        << "Input data" << endl
        << "==========" << endl
        << "Enter the number of kingdoms: ";
    cin >> count;
    cin.ignore();

    // TODO: allocate dynamic memory here for the pKingdoms pointer
    pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        // TODO: add code to accept user input for the pKingdoms array
        cout << "Enter the name for kingdom #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> pKingdoms[i].m_name;
        cout << "Enter the number people living in " << pKingdoms[i].m_name << ": ";
        cin >> pKingdoms[i].m_population;
    }
    cout << "==========" << endl << endl;


    // testing that "display(...)" works
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl
        << "The first kingdom of Westeros" << endl
        << "------------------------------" << endl;
    display(pKingdoms[0]);
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;


    // testing that the first overload of "display(...)" works
    display(pKingdoms, count);
    cout << endl;


    // testing that the second overload of "display(...)" works
    display(pKingdoms, count, 345678);
    cout << endl;


    // testing that the third overload of "display(...)" works
    display(pKingdoms, count, "Mordor");
    cout << endl;

    display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale");
    cout << endl;

    // TODO: deallocate the dynamic memory here
    delete[] pKingdoms;

    return 0;
}
```

Lastly, my struct in my `kingdom.h` file included is:

```
namespace westeros {
struct Kingdom {
    char m_name[9];
    int m_population;
};
void display(Kingdom& p);
void display(Kingdom* a, int index);
void display(Kingdom* a, int index, int min);
void display(Kingdom* a, int index, const char *n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like `strcmp` to compare the *content* of 2 strings; as it is, you are comparing their *locations* in memory, which (as you have seen) are not the same.